# How to stop a rouge queries inflating your billing when using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to automatically kill/stop a query if its taking more than specified resources (either in terms of time or number of rows/data to be scanned) ?

Thanks
Gour

Answer (score 2):

There is a documentation page about [BigQuery Best Practices: Controlling Costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) which described all methods:

- Avoid SELECT *
- Sample data using preview options
- Price your queries before running them with dry-run before
- Limit query costs by restricting the number of bytes billed
- View costs using a dashboard and query your audit logs
- other methods on the docs page, such as partitioning, clustering etc...

but essentially you can program on the dry-run or the number of bytes billed feature to stop execution.